# how do i differentiate between two different JButtons in actionPerformed?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener

so i have my JButtons

```
public static JButton textYes = new JButton("Yes");
public static JButton textNo = new JButton("No");
```

my menus

```
public static String choiceReroll = "";
public static String menu = "";
```

and my main() method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Greed gui = new Greed();
    gui.launchFrame();
    redirectSystemStreams();

    Container contentPane = f.getContentPane();
    contentPane.add(new Greed());

    Scanner is = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to Greed...");
        do {
    System.out.println("Would you like to play? (yes/no)");
    menu = is.next();
            switch (menu) {
                case "yes":
                    jTextArea1.setText(null);
                    diceOne = 0;
                    diceTwo = 0;
                    diceThree = 0;
                    diceFour = 0;
                    diceFive = 0;
                    System.out.println("Rolling...");
                    Game();

                    break;
                case "no":
                    System.out.println("Goodbye...");
                    System.exit(0);

                    break;
                default:
                    invalidInput();

                    break;
            }
        } while (!"yes".equals(menu) || !"no".equals(menu));
}
```

then i have my actionListeners

```
textYes.addActionListener(this);
textNo.addActionListener(this);
```

how do i make it so that when i click on one button or the other, it will enter text where it requests user input at `menu = is.next();`

i also want it to just enter text, depending on which button it clicked on. and have it enter the text, no matter what variable is asking for input

for example:

`menu = is.next();`

vs.

`choiceReroll = is.next();`

EDIT: more info...

and i also have my performedAction() method

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    jTextArea1.setText(null);
    if (box1.isSelected()) {
        System.out.println("1 is selected");
        willRerollDiceOne = true;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("1 not selected");
        willRerollDiceOne = false;
    }
    if (box2.isSelected()) {
        System.out.println("2 is selected");
        willRerollDiceTwo = true;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("2 not selected");
        willRerollDiceTwo = false;
    }
    if (box3.isSelected()) {
        System.out.println("3 is selected");
        willRerollDiceThree = true;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("3 not selected");
        willRerollDiceThree = false;
    }
    if (box4.isSelected()) {
        System.out.println("4 is selected");
        willRerollDiceFour = true;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("4 not selected");
        willRerollDiceFour = false;
    }
    if (box5.isSelected()) {
        System.out.println("5 is selected");
        willRerollDiceFive = true;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("5 not selected");
        willRerollDiceFive = false;
    }
```

EDIT: i added the actionPerformed for the buttons, but am only going to show one for now

```
    if (area == "menu") {
        if(e.getSource() == textYes){
            menu = "yes";
        }
        if(e.getSource() == textNo){
            menu = "no";
        }
    }
```

but when i click the button, it doesn't update, why?
how do i fix this?

EDIT: added a "test" printout inside the if statement

```
    if ("menu".equals(area)) {
            if(e.getSource() == textYes){
                menu = "yes";
                System.out.println("test");
            }
            if(e.getSource() == textNo){
                menu = "no";
            }
```

prints "test" every time i click the yes button

EDIT: This is the rest of the method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Greed gui = new Greed();
        gui.launchFrame();
        redirectSystemStreams();

        Container contentPane = f.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(new Greed());

        Scanner is = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Greed...");
            do {
        System.out.println("Would you like to play? (yes/no)");
        area = "menu";
        menu = is.next();
                switch (menu) {
                    case "yes":
                        jTextArea1.setText(null);
                        diceOne = 0;
                        diceTwo = 0;
                        diceThree = 0;
                        diceFour = 0;
                        diceFive = 0;
                        System.out.println("Rolling...");
                        Game();

                        break;
                    case "no":
                        System.out.println("Goodbye...");
                        System.exit(0);

                        break;
                    default:
                        invalidInput();

                        break;
                }
            } while (!"yes".equals(menu) || !"no".equals(menu));
        area = "";
    }

    public static void Game() throws IOException {
        rollDiceOne();
        rollDiceTwo();
        rollDiceThree();
        rollDiceFour();
        rollDiceFive();

        //displayDice();
        displayDiceValues();
        f.validate();
        f.repaint();

        choiceRerollDice();
    }

    public static void choiceRerollDice() {
        Scanner is = new Scanner(System.in);
            do {
                if (!canRerollDiceOne && !canRerollDiceTwo && !canRerollDiceThree && !canRerollDiceFour && !canRerollDiceFive) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, but you may not reroll any more dice...");
                displayDiceValues();
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else {
        System.out.println("Would you like to reroll any (more) dice? (yes/no)");
            choiceReroll = is.next();
                switch (choiceReroll) {
                    case "yes":
                        rerollDice();
                        break;
                    case "no":
                        //endTurn();
                        displayDiceValues();
                        f.repaint();
                        //calculatePlayer1Score();
                        //System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                        //System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                        System.exit(0);
                    default:
                        invalidInput();
                    }
                }
            } while (!"yes".equals(choiceReroll) || !"no".equals(choiceReroll));
    }

    public static void rerollDice() {
        Scanner is = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Which dice would you like to reroll? (Click the box under the dice!)");
        rollSel = is.next();
        switch (rollSel) {
            case "roll":
            if (willRerollDiceOne) {
                if (canRerollDiceOne) {
                    diceOne = 0;
                    rollDiceOne();
                    canRerollDiceOne = false;
                    box1.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("error");
                }
            }

            else {
            }
            if (willRerollDiceTwo) {
                if (canRerollDiceTwo) {
                diceTwo = 0;
                rollDiceTwo();
                canRerollDiceTwo = false;
                box2.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("error");
                }
            }
            else {
            }
            if (willRerollDiceThree) {
                if (canRerollDiceThree) {
                diceThree = 0;
                rollDiceThree();
                canRerollDiceThree = false;
                box3.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
            else {
            }
            if (willRerollDiceFour) {
                if (canRerollDiceFour) {
                diceFour = 0;
                rollDiceFour();
                canRerollDiceFour = false;
                box4.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
            else {
            }
            if (willRerollDiceFive) {
                if (canRerollDiceFive) {
                diceFive = 0;
                rollDiceFive();
                canRerollDiceFive = false;
                box5.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
            else {
            }
            box1.setSelected(false);
            box2.setSelected(false);
            box3.setSelected(false);
            box4.setSelected(false);
            box5.setSelected(false);
            f.validate();
            f.repaint();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Error...");
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `actionPerformed` method just do :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    if(e.getSource() == textYes){
      //perform action when textYes clicked
    }
    if(e.getSource() == textNo){
      //perform action when textNo clicked
    }
}
```

Instead of this :

```
Scanner is = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Greed...");
            do {
        System.out.println("Would you like to play? (yes/no)");
        area = "menu";
        menu = is.next();
                switch (menu) {
                    case "yes":
                        jTextArea1.setText(null);
                        diceOne = 0;
                        diceTwo = 0;
                        diceThree = 0;
                        diceFour = 0;
                        diceFive = 0;
                        System.out.println("Rolling...");
                        Game();

                        break;
                    case "no":
                        System.out.println("Goodbye...");
                        System.exit(0);

                        break;
                    default:
                        invalidInput();

                        break;
                }
            } while (!"yes".equals(menu) || !"no".equals(menu));
        area = "";
```

You could create a method that will take the input as a parameter.

```
public void start(String menu){
                switch (menu) {
                    case "yes":
                        jTextArea1.setText(null);
                        diceOne = 0;
                        diceTwo = 0;
                        diceThree = 0;
                        diceFour = 0;
                        diceFive = 0;
                        System.out.println("Rolling...");
                        Game();

                        break;
                    case "no":
                        System.out.println("Goodbye...");
                        System.exit(0);

                        break;
                    default:
                        invalidInput();

                        break;
                }
}
```

Then in the action performed, just do :

```
if(e.getSource() == textYes){
            start("yes");
        }
        if(e.getSource() == textNo){
            start("no");
        }
```

Comment: that helped! and i also added another edit at the bottom, if you could check that, that would be amazing! thanks man!

Comment: Don't compare strings with `==` . Use `if(area.equals("menu")) `

Comment: ok, i fixed it, but it still doesn't update? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is area equals to menu when you click on the button ? Try to print area before the if statement.

Comment: yup, it does. any idea on why it's not updating?

Comment: 1) Try to sysout("hello") inside the if statement for the getSource() to see if the action is performed i.e (`if(e.getSource() == textYes){            menu = "yes";System.out.println("test");})`. Post your code updated.

Comment: yup it prints "test" every time i click the button

Comment: any ideas on this? @ZouZou

Comment: @pwnster1357 The problem is not here then. The event on the button works. So what's the problem you're facing ?

Comment: when i click it, it sets the menu to yes, but does not proceed through the rest of the method

Comment: i actually couldn't fit it all so i just added the three methods being used the most

Comment: I don't see where you're using the actionPerformed method. Could you give me a concrete example ?

Comment: EDIT: more info...

and i also have my performedAction() method

Comment: look for that in my original post, and i have actionListeners attached to both buttons, and it sets menu to yes or no, but it simply does not proceed through the method. i think it's because `menu = is.next();` is still waiting for input. any suggestions?

Comment: ya im starting to think the problem is where it asks for input, probably because the value of menu is being changed and not entered, any ideas on how to get around this? there has to be a way :l

Comment: @pwnster1357 I think I understand your problem. You have two buttons and if the user click yes you want to enter in the first case of your switch ?

Comment: grrrr I always forget how to call methods like `public static void start(String menu) throws IOException {` :l

Comment: well i started out with command line, then started changing it to gui lol

Comment: try it and see what happens.

Comment: it gives me: `unreported IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown.` I can't `throws IOException` to `performedAction()` as it won't allow it. and i absolutely hate try-catch lol, any thoughts?

Comment: Are you reading or accessing a file somewhere ? If yes you could just make your method throws the exception : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707906/unreported-exception-java-io-ioexception-must-be-caught-or-declared-to-be-throw

Comment: I am not accessing any files anywhere :l

Comment: Ok, sure thing, just give me a second.

Comment: oh and that second `if ("menu".equals(area)) {` should have been commented... woops

Comment: @pwnster1357 You should avoid mixin command line and GUI. I just commented the method choiceRerollDice(). Now you can continue modify to let the user re-choose. Have a nice coding =)

Comment: Thanks so much man! Now I can just merge the two to get it to do exactly what I want! :D Cya round!

Answer (score 4):

> how do i differentiate between two different JButtons in actionPerformed?
>   i have my actionListeners

```
textYes.addActionListener(this);
textNo.addActionListener(this);
```

The cleanest approach is to use separate listeners. You can do this with an anonymous inner class, like

```
textYes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        // here you can do any necessary actions for the "Yes" button,
        // like calling a specific method of the outer class which handles the event
    }
});

textNo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        // here you can do any necessary actions for the "No" button,
        // like calling a specific method of the outer class which handles the event
    }
});
```

If you still want to use one action listener only, the [`getSource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29) method from `ActionEvent` allows you to access the source of the event, as @ZouZou already mentioned.

See also [How do you add an ActionListener onto a JButton in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284899/how-do-you-add-an-actionlistener-onto-a-jbutton-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

From the [ActionEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html), you can get the [action command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand%28%29). So, just [set an action command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setActionCommand%28java.lang.String%29) to each button to identify them.

Answer (score 1):

[getSource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29) is specified by the EventObject class that ActionEvent is a child of `(via java.awt.AWTEvent).` This gives you a reference to the object that the event came from

Or either set command for each JButton using `setActionComman(String command)` and then fetch relevant action Command Using `getActionCommand`.

```
String cmd = event.getActionCommand();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign different `ActionListener` to each field. I strongly advise you to do that, and not extend the Container that has those fields with `ActionListener` and pass it as `this`. It preserves encapsulation, it enforces separation of concerns and its a matter of clean, understandable code.

So, each button should have `ActionListener` added like this:

```
textYes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(Action event e) {
        //logic
    }
});
```