# Java, Catching an exception and passing it to a method

Tags: java, methods, exception, io

I created a method that accepts an IOException as an argument.  This method opens the out stream and prints information about the exception to a text file.  My problem that I seem to be running into.. How to call that method from a catch block?

```
try{
    if(true)
        throw new IOException();
}
catch(IOException e){
    //pass it to a method
}
```

:::EDIT:::

```
public void logErrors(IOException e){
    PrintWriter out = yada yada;

    out.println(e.getCause());
}
```

Comment: it is simply `yourMethod(e);`

Comment: callthemethodyouwant(e);

Comment: If you're getting an IOException you probably shouldn't be trying to use an out stream after catching it, because that's what might have caused the error in the first place.

Comment: Why do this? Why catch the same exception that you're throwing within this short piece of code? Why not simply do: `if (...) { myMethod(); }` and leave exceptions out of this?

Comment: @Leah, I tried.. it says "unreported exception... must be thrown or caught"

Comment: @Zar, You might be right.. opening the stream within that method does throw another IOException.. Perhaps the problem lies within my method..

Comment: I suspect you've invented a bicycle :) Use logger, [for instance slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/). There are methods to log exceptions.

Comment: @Podis .Can you post the whole method if possible.It might be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707906/unreported-exception-java-io-ioexception-must-be-caught-or-declared-to-be-throw

Comment: You are getting yourself into a loop. Every time you try to use an output stream you have to catch an IOException, and if you try to log that error in a file you're back where you started. Like Rafael said, you might want to reconsider how you log your errors.

Comment: So.. Thanks to everyone for the help.  It was a little confusing because I missed that NetBeans auto-implemented a throws clause in there.. just one of those overlooked things.  It's working now =)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just have to call the name of the method, where you want the method's code to be executed like this:

```
try{
    if(true)
        throw new IOException();
}
catch(IOException e){
    //pass it to a method
    methodToExecute(e);
}

also, I can see that you throw an IOException in both cases so perhaps 
you may want to consider modifying the code to use a finally block
```

EDIT

On second thought, you can just use an if statement to throw it always.

```
if (...)
{
   yourMethod(throw new IOException());
}
```